# Gte the list of tables with similar first name

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

In my Android database, I have number of tables. Among these tables, some contain similar names starting from "List_". For an example, there are tables like "List_A", "List_B", "List_C" etc. How can I get the list of all tables which starts from the word "List_" using code?

Comment: [Sqlite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
public void grabTables() {
    Cursor cur = this.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master where name like 'List_%'", new String[0]);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    String tableName;

    while (cur.getPosition() < cur.getCount()) {
        tableName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("name"));
        System.out.println("Table Name = " + tableName);
        cur.moveToNext();
    }
    cur.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick :)

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbname.sqlite_master 
WHERE type='table'
AND name LIKE 'List_%'
```